# Нужна ли запятая перед "о ком"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Мы заботимся о ком можем.*

Нужна ли здесь запятая? Мне интуиция и правило про цельные по смыслу выражения подсказывают, что нет. Но, возможно, это не тот случай.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение О КОМ МОЖЕМ (ср.: кто может) действительно воспринимается как фразеологический оборот. Кроме того, оно употреблено в качестве дополнения к несвободному глаголу - сказуемому ЗАБОТИМСЯ. Это выражение легко можно заменить местоимением с предлогом "обо всех".

[Розенталь. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=145#pp145) Фразеологический оборот не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения и обычно эквивалентен члену предложения. Так, в сочетании "говорит об этом ***где только может***" выделенные слова имеют значение ‘везде’.

Поэтому запятую ставить не нужно.